# Finding the fill color of a draggable shape with Kineticjs

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have two circles with different colors and I want to get the fill color of the dragged circle once the user has let go of the object using the `dragend` event.

```
shapes = new Kinetic.Layer();

circle1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
   x: stage.getWidth() / 3.2,
   y: stage.getHeight() / 3.2,
   radius: radius,
   fill: "blue",
   stroke: "black",
   strokeWidth: 4,
   name: "circle",
   draggable: true
});  

circle2 = new Kinetic.Circle({
   x: stage.getWidth() / 1.5,
   y: stage.getHeight() / 1.4,
   radius: radius,
   fill: "yellow",
   stroke: "black",
   strokeWidth: 4,
   name: "circle",
   draggable: true
 });  

 shapes.add(circle1);
 shapes.add(circle2);
 stage.add(shapes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a handler to the shape and use [`getFill()`](http://www.kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Shape.php#getFill)

```
function iGetFill(){
    var color = this.getFill();
}

circle1.on('dragend',function(){
    iGetFill.apply(this);
});

circle2.on('dragend',function(){
    iGetFill.apply(this);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to get this value for other circles in the layer. So dragging circle1 or circle2 would call the same function.

Comment: @Zach add handlers for them as well. then have the callback call a common function.